# Why can some point $P_0$ be a critical point of a function $f$ if $\nabla f(P_0)$ is undefined?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

The definition of a critical point from my textbook states:

> A point $P_0$ which is not on the boundary of the domain is called
> *critical point* of the function if the gradient $\nabla f(P_0)$ is either
> $\vec{0}$ or undefined

I have 3 issues with this:

1. Why cannot it be on the boundary? My thinking is that not all limits exist at every point. But still, why would that be an issue? Why a local maximum cannot be on a boundary if the function takes the highest value at that point?
2. If $\nabla f(P_0)$ is undefined it means that at least one of the partial derivatives doesn't exist at $P_0$. Why would this imply that $P_0$ is a critical point? What if the function is discontinuous at $P_0$, then the derivative wouldn't exist and $\nabla f(P_0)$ would be undefined. How does it make sense that $P_0$ is a critical point then
3. Similar to 2), what if the function is continuous at $P_0$, but not all limits exist at $P_0$. An example would be boundary point, which is excluded, but why would it be excluded? Just to allow for us to define a critical point as

> $\nabla f(P_0)$ is either $\vec{0}$ or undefined

, and not just $\nabla f(P_0) = \vec{0}$?

What is confusing me the most is why constructing the definition of a critical point such as considering the point with an undefined gradient as the critical point. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Think of the univariate function $f(x) = |x|$. Clearly, its derivative is not defined at $x = 0$. However,  it is obviously reasonable to consider $x = 0$ as a critical point.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that sometimes people call the points where the derivatives is undefined the singular points. I do not like it that much if they are included in the definition of critical points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a standard argument to rule out some points as being the location of a local/global max or min. Roughly it goes:

If $P$ is in the interior of the domain and $\nabla f(P)$ is defined and not $0$ then (by using the tangent plane approximation) we can find points $P'$ and $P''$ in the domain, close to $P$, and such that $$ f(P') < f(P) < f(P'').$$

A **critical point** is defined to be a place in the interior of the domain where this argument doesn't work, and which we therefore have **not** ruled out as the location of a local/global max/min.

In the end we know that any local/global max/min is either on the boundary or is at a critical point.

Comment: That makes sense (+1). But it still doesn't address the issues of 1) why can't the critical point be on the boundary and 2) why *every* point with an undefined gradient has to be the critical point (such as the point where the function is discontinuous).

Comment: 1) We need to analyze the **whole** boundary in order to understand possible maxs/mins. Why bother to single out some of such points as critical points if we're going to analyze all boundary points anyway. 2) Critical points are, by intention, the points in the interior of the domain which we have to analyze separately. Points of discontinuity of the function definitely fall into that category. On the interior, if the proof I outlined doesn't apply, we have to check it. We call the points we have to check: critical points.